# Object is possibly 'null' Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

I seem to have encountered an issue where it tells me that the object's are possibly null. I have looked online and on StackOverflow and tries a dozen fixes to no success. I am trying to insert the text "test" into the html elements using their id's.

```
  var cname = document.getElementById("chargername");
  var cloc = document.getElementById("chargerlocation");
  var ctype = document.getElementById("chargertype");
  var cdesc = document.getElementById("chargerdescription");
  var crating = document.getElementById("chargerrating");

  function handleClick() {
    cname.innerHTML = "test";
    cloc.innerHTML = "test";
    ctype.innerHTML = "test";
    cdesc.innerHTML = "test";
    crating.innerHTML = "test";
  }
```

I get this error: "TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')"

Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: You should avoid `innerHtml` instead use `textContent`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is what I did finally to fix this error:

```
var cname = docSelect.name;
var cloc = docSelect.location;
var ctype = docSelect.types;
var cdesc = docSelect.description.substring(0, 90) + "...";
var clink = `/chargers/${props}`;
document.getElementsByClassName("chargername")[0].innerHTML = cname;
document.getElementsByClassName("chargerlocation")[0].innerHTML = cloc;
document.getElementsByClassName("chargertype")[0].innerHTML = ctype;
document.getElementsByClassName("chargerdescription")[0].innerHTML = cdesc;
```

Thanks to everyone who responded to my plea for help :)

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to the fact that the code is executed before the `dom` is loaded and hence be `null`

First check where the script is loaded.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="index.js"></script>  <!-- If the script is placed here then there is a high chance it is executed before dom is loaded -->
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

If the script is placed in the head tag then there is a high chance it is executed before dom is loaded.

You can add the onLoad script to detect that the dom is loaded and then execute your script.

You can refer [here](https://www.skillsugar.com/how-to-use-document-onload-in-javascript) to get see the implementation

Something like this should work for you.

```
window.onload = function () {
  function elmById(idName: string): HTMLElement {
    return document.getElementById(idName) as HTMLElement;
  }

  const cloc = elmById('chargerlocation');
  const ctype = elmById('chargertype');
  const cdesc = elmById('chargerdescription');
  const crating = elmById('chargerrating');

  function handleClick() {
    cloc.innerHTML = 'test';
    ctype.innerHTML = 'test';
    cdesc.innerHTML = 'test';
    crating.innerHTML = 'test';
  }
};
```

Comment: This may work but now I am unsure how to call the handleClick function from a button onClick event

Answer (score -1):

You can tell typescript that the element wont be null with `as HTMLElement`:

```
let cloc = document.getElementById("chargerlocation") as HTMLElement;
let ctype = document.getElementById("chargertype") as HTMLElement;
let cdesc = document.getElementById("chargerdescription") as HTMLElement;
let crating = document.getElementById("chargerrating") as HTMLElement;

function handleClick() {
  cloc.innerHTML = "test";
  ctype.innerHTML = "test";
  cdesc.innerHTML = "test";
  crating.innerHTML = "test";
}
```

You can also use the exclamation mark `!`. It is the non-null assertion operator. It removes null and undefined from the type. Like so:

```
  let cloc = document.getElementById("chargerlocation");
  let ctype = document.getElementById("chargertype");
  let cdesc = document.getElementById("chargerdescription");
  let crating = document.getElementById("chargerrating");

  function handleClick() {
    cloc!.innerHTML = "test";
    ctype!.innerHTML = "test";
    cdesc!.innerHTML = "test";
    crating!.innerHTML = "test";
  }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=4&pln=1&pc=1#code/ATD0uAbBTAXYDGA7AhgW2sAvMAJtAMxQFdJ4UBnYACQBUBZAGQFEYMlYAoEGeBSAPYJseIcXawAdAHM4raBIBCATwCSuABQAiBAAsUAJ1kHBCFLACWApFoCUAbm5Q4iWMoAOmHLjESZctmgOFXVtPUNjN087Rx4XBHwKYW9fIKlZWHklNU0dfSNoA0SEAwt3S2sYp15EA3MLJGkRHwRxNP9MwOCcsPzjOstGqqcCYiQECqRgfSRcGABhSAsEAGsNW2AAbycQcERUDEkGpEK6JhEtWGgKWC1YkERTAEIjpBODM8YLq5u7ndcPNAXsdTgwvjhLtdbvcQAlrghgW9QecIT9of8SvVGoj3p9vlC-iAAL5AA)

Comment: this unsafe... I would recommend adding null checking... the element might not exist and then the code will crash

Comment: This fix removes the error in vscode although still gives me one when running the function

Comment: that is another question then :)

Comment: Thanks @rustyBucketBay for your help, however this is where I got to by myself and just needed help with fixing the function itself.

Comment: Better yet, use the [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator).